# Determine the index where the elements in the input array satisfy conditions of 2 reference arrays without using loop in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an input array a:

```
a = np.array([120,350,410,354,247])
```

And two reference arrays which form the upper and lower limits for *a*:

```
lower = np.array([100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450])
upper = np.array([150,200,250,300,350,400,450,500])
```

The input and reference arrays can be of different lengths.

My goal is to find out the index of the *lower* and *upper* arrays  that satisfies `lower <= a < upper` *without* using a loop in python. So I am looking for a way to obtain the following output for the above example *without* looping:

```
output = [0,5,6,5,2]
```

Comment: How do you obtain the output? Show the loop please.

Comment: Also, what happens when none of the elements are satisfactory? Or is there guaranteed to be at least one solution per element of the bounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `a.reshape(-1,1)` let's us create a column vector out of `a`. If we compare it against a 1D array (`lower`) it returns the comparison for each element in `a` against the whole 1D array (`lower`).

```
np.argmax((lower <= a.reshape(-1, 1)) & (a.reshape(-1, 1) < upper), axis=1)
```

returns

```
[0 5 6 5 2]
```